# Adicionar un espacio entre cada caracter

Tags: java, regex, string

Intento separar los caracteres de un `String` por medio de espacios usando una expresión regular. Es decir `111` resulta `1 1 1` o `ABC` resulta `A B C`  y la salida debería ser un String.

```
String nombre = "111";
nombre = nombre.replaceAll("\\ˆ\\w\\s", nombre);
```

Resultado esperado: `"1 1 1"`;

Comment: @mariano la salida es un `String`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reemplazando en las posiciones que no sean ni el inicio ni el final del texto:

```
texto = texto.replaceAll("(?!^|$)", " ");
```

O, sin regex (eliminando cualquier espacio que tenga al inicio/fin):

```
texto = texto.replace("", " ").trim();
```

O, llevando a la forma generalizada para separar cada N caracteres:

```
final int cadaN = 2;
final String separarCon = " ";

String texto = "probando!";

texto = texto.replaceAll("(?s).{" + cadaN + "}(?!$)", "$0" + separarCon);


System.out.println(texto);
```

```
pr ob an do !
```

- ya que coincide con los N caracteres, siempre que no esté seguido por el final del texto `(?!$)`, y lo reemplaza por lo que coincidió `$0` seguido del espacio. El modo `(?s)` es para que también pueda coincidir con saltos de línea, si hubiera.